# calling c++ function with template in objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c++

im trying to call a c++ template function in objective c that looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void test() {
    ...

    std::cout << "hello world! \n";
}
```

Im getting the following error with calling `test()` :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"test()", referenced from:
 -[viewController onNext] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

if i take out `template<typename T>` it works fine, however, i need to use some functions from a c++ library that require templates and i cant get around it. any idea on whats happening?

I have no experience with c++ what so ever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, when you call a templated function, if the template parameter (i.e. T in your code) can't be deduced from the parameter passed to the function (which is your case since your function doesn't have any parameter), you shall call the function like this:

test< someType >();

Answer (score 1):

In C++:

- `void test()`
- `template<>void test<int>()`
- `template<>void test<float>()`

(as examples) are all different symbols. by removing the template/parameter, it's a different symbol which matches the one you call in `-[viewController onNext]`.